# Identifying conflicting dates on create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Making a reservation app. How can I check or validate the date for example `date_start` and `date_end` has the value of

```
date_start  date_end 
26-11-2017  27-11-2017
```

I will create another reservation which has these starting and end date values but it conflicts with the other values. How can I check for conflicting dates?

```
date_start  date_end 
25-11-2017  28-11-2017
```

Used this to validate the dates in between

Model

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap

scope :overlapping, ->(period_start, period_end) do
  where "((date_start <= ?) and (date_end >= ?))", period_end, period_start
end

private

def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.overlapping(date_start, date_end).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

View - choosing the date

```
<%= f.label :'date_start:' %>
<%= f.date_field :date_start %>

<%= f.label :'date_end:' %>
<%= f.date_field :date_end %>
```

Sample dates 26 to 27 are already booked/reserved supposedly the it must prevent from inserting 25 to 28 because 26 to 27 are already booked.

Comment: What is the problem in your code?

Comment: @Imran I want to be able to add a validation to check for conflicts between the dates above. Sample dates 26 to 27 are already booked/reserved supposedly the app must prevent from inserting 25 to 28 because 26 to 27 are already booked.

Comment: What database are you using (if you want a SQL-based solution)?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall mysql

Answer (score 6):

Model:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
    validate :overlapping
    private
    def overlapping
    if Reservation.where('? <  date_end and ? > date_start', self.date_start, self.date_end).any?
        errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another')
    end
end
```

Schema:

```
    create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.date     "date_start"
        t.date     "date_end"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end
```

Here is `rails console` log after I tried to create (24 nov - 27 nov) and (25 nov - 27 nov) when there was (25 nov - 26 nov)

```
irb(main):003:0> Reservation.create date_start: Date.parse('25-11-2017'), date_end: Date.parse('26-11-2017')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations" WHERE ('2017-11-25'  date_start)
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "reservations" ("date_start", "date_end", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["date_start", "2017-11-25"], ["date_end", "2017-11-26"], ["created_at", "2017-11-21 13:23:05.192276"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-21 13:23:05.192276"]]
   (10.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #
irb(main):004:0> Reservation.create date_start: Date.parse('24-11-2017'), date_end: Date.parse('27-11-2017')
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations" WHERE ('2017-11-24'  date_start)
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #
irb(main):005:0> Reservation.create date_start: Date.parse('25-11-2017'), date_end: Date.parse('26-11-2017')
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations" WHERE ('2017-11-25'  date_start)
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #
```

There are rollbacks as expected.

Comment: No it still inserts the date created a reservation for nov 25-26 and the same user will now create another reservation for nov 24-27 this is supposedly is an error because nov 25-26 is already booked, how can I check or validate the date so it doesn't conflict with the other dates?

Answer (score 4):

your validation is not working because you are checking that the new reservation dates are between the reservations dates already existing in the database. In the specific case you have mentioned, You need to check  existing reservations dates are between dates in the new reservation dates.

Example mentioned in the question for reference:

*Already existing reservation in the database*

```
date_start  date_end 
26-11-2017  27-11-2017
```

*New reservation:*

```
date_start  date_end 
25-11-2017  28-11-2017
```

**You need to check for the following cases:**

**Notation**:

- **R1** is the reservation already existing in the database
- **R2** is the new reservation user is trying to add.
- **|** is representing the start date and the end date

**Case1**

> ```
>     |------R1------|
>      ____|------R2------|
> ```

when R1 starts and ends before R2

**Case2**

> ```
>     ______|------R1------|
>    |------R2------|______
> ```

when R2 starts and ends before R1

**Case3**

> ```
>    ___|------R1------|___
>    |---------R2---------|
> ```

When R2 contains R1. (The case you have mentioned in your question)

**Case4**

> ```
>      |---------R1---------|
>      __|------R2------|___
> ```

When R1 contains R2. (This is the only case you have covered in your **overlapping** scope)

Disclaimer: The scope below is untested and might have some issues. (You can easily write a SQL query by covering all the cases above)

```
    scope :overlapping, ->(period_start, period_end) do  
            where(
                "(:period_start <= date_start AND :period_end < date_end AND :period_start > :period_end) OR
                 (:period_start >= date_start AND :period_end > date_end AND :period_start < date_end) OR
                 (:period_start < date_start AND :period_end >= date_end) OR
                 (:period_start >= date_start AND :period_end <= date_end)",period_start: period_start, period_end: period_end)
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

- There will be many dates on you reservations table. for example:

  - reservation one: 7.days.from_now ~ 6.days.from_now
  - reservation two: 3.days.from_now ~ 1.days.from_now
- Which means you have to recognize the reserved date by each range.

  - originally: 1~3, 6~7
- I used a hash to index reserved dates, like this:

  - not available dates (from now): 1, 2, 3, 6, 7
  - also, you can create efficient index narrowed by searching (or scoping) only the target date_start and date_end or active reservations

Model:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
    validate :exclusive_reservation?

    def exclusive_reservation?
        result = true
        reserved = {}

        Reservation.pluck(:date_start, :date_end).each do |date_range|
            (date_range.first..date_range.second).each do |date| 
                reserved[date] = true
            end
        end

        if reserved.has_key? self.date_start
            errors.add(:date_start, 'it overlaps another reservation')
            result = false
        end

        if reserved.has_key? self.date_end
            errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
            result = false
        end

        result
    end
end
```